# Searching for an embedded array in MongoDB (with Java)

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a document `investor` with the following contents:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("588ced539df613f71a697bb9"),
    "idInvestor": 1,
    "username": "Alexander Hamilton",
    "password": "123456",
    "email": "alex.hamil@gmail.com",
    "name": "Alexander Hamilton",
    "idProfile": 1,
    "questionAnswer": [{
        "**idQuestion**": 1,
        "idAnswer": 1
    }, {
        "**idQuestion**": 2,
        "idAnswer": 1
    }...]
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the idQuestions for `idinvestor: 1` to store them inside an ArrayList. I'm able to get the other attributes that aren't in the embedded with something like this:

```
Investor investor= new Investor();
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("finnovate");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("investor");
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("username", username)).first();
investor.setIdInvestor(myDoc.getDouble("idInvestor").intValue());
```

But I'm not understanding how I can get all the idQuestion values. Can someone shed a light on this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have array of documents as "questionAnswer" in Mongo, so in Java it will be ArrayList of Document. From myDoc you can do this:

```
List<Document> questionAnswers = (List<Document>)myDoc.get("questionAnswer");
for (Document questionAnswer: questionAnswers) {
    // do whatever you need here
    System.out.println(questionAnswer.getString("idQuestion"));
}
```

Or you can use aggregation to select idQuestion directly.

```
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("username", username)),
        Aggregates.unwind("$questionAnswer"),
        Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.excludeId(), 
                Projections.computed("idQuestion", "$questionAnswer.idQuestion"), 
                Projections.computed("idAnswer", "$questionAnswer.idAnswer")
        ))
)).forEach(doWhateverYouNeed);
```

And handling block for results:

```
Block<Document> doWhateverYouNeed = new Block<Document>() {
     @Override
     public void apply(final Document document) {
         //do whatever you need here
         System.out.println(document.toJson());
     }
};
```